# Convert data-time to date or time with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a an data file that contains date-time information, but I only need the date or the time at the end.

Is it possible to convert such data to excise only the part that I need using XSLT?

Here is the sample XML:

```
 <sessions>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015 7:30:00 AM</starttime>
 <endtime>10/25/2015 11:30:00 AM</endtime>
 <sessionname>Convention Center - 710</sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Simulation</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>572</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Certificate of Completion - Hands on Assessment</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015 7:30:00 AM</starttime>
 <endtime>10/25/2015 11:30:00 AM</endtime>
 <sessionname>Convention Center - 710</sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Simulation</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>572</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Certificate of Completion - Hands on Assessment</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015 7:30:00 AM</starttime>
 <endtime>10/25/2015 11:30:00 AM</endtime>
 <sessionname>Convention Center - 710</sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Simulation</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>572</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Certificate of Completion - Hands on Assessment</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015 7:30:00 AM</starttime>
 <endtime>10/25/2015 11:30:00 AM</endtime>
 <sessionname>Convention Center - 710</sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Simulation</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>580</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Certificate of Completion - Hands on Assessment</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015 7:30:00 AM</starttime>
 <endtime>10/25/2015 5:30:00 PM</endtime>
 <sessionname></sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Self-Study</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>308</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Self-study in ICU Airway Management</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 </sessions>
```

I'd like to create final XML that looks like this:

```
 <sessions>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015</starttime>
 <endtime>11:30:00 AM</endtime>
 <sessionname>Convention Center - 710</sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Simulation</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>572</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Certificate of Completion - Hands on Assessment</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015</starttime>
 <endtime>11:30:00 AM</endtime>
 <sessionname>Convention Center - 710</sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Simulation</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>572</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Certificate of Completion - Hands on Assessment</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015</starttime>
 <endtime>11:30:00 AM</endtime>
 <sessionname>Convention Center - 710</sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Simulation</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>572</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Certificate of Completion - Hands on Assessment</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015</starttime>
 <endtime>11:30:00 AM</endtime>
 <sessionname>Convention Center - 710</sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Simulation</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>580</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Certificate of Completion - Hands on Assessment</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 <session>
 <starttime>10/25/2015</starttime>
 <endtime>5:30:00 PM</endtime>
 <sessionname></sessionname>
 <sessiontype>Self-Study</sessiontype>
 <sessionID>308</sessionID>
 <sessionDesc>Self-study in ICU Airway Management</sessionDesc>
 </session>
 </sessions>
```

Here's the XSLT that I'm starting with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="sessions">
<sessions><xsl:for-each select="session">
<session>
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</session></xsl:for-each></sessions>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="starttime"><starttime><xsl:value-of select="."/></starttime></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="endtime"><endtime><xsl:value-of select="."/></endtime></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="sessionname"><sessioname><xsl:value-of select="."/></sessioname></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="sessiontype"><sessiontype><xsl:value-of select="."/> </sessiontype> </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="sessionID"><sessionID><xsl:value-of select="."/></sessionID> </xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="sessionDesc"><sessionDesc><xsl:value-of select="."/>   </sessionDesc> </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
substring-before(starttime, ' ')
```

to extract the date and:

```
 substring-after(endtime, ' ')
```

to extract the time.

**Note**:
In situations like these, where you want to preserve most of the input as is, and only make a few changes, it is convenient to use the *identity transform* template as the rule, and add additional templates as the exceptions:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="starttime">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' ')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="endtime">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' ')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does this match the data BEFORE the space? Is that how it picks up the date versus the time?

What would it look like if the the date-time appeared as "7:30:00 AM 10/25/2015" instead.

Comment: "*Does this match the data BEFORE the space?*"  No, it **extracts** the substring before the (first) space (the word *match* has a very specific meaning in XSLT). -- "*What would it look like if the the date-time appeared as "7:30:00 AM 10/25/2015" instead.*" You would simply use `substring-after()` to extract the date part, and `substring-before()` to extract the time part.

Comment: But if you use the 'substring-after' function would it not extract the 'AM' as part of the AFTER string, such as "AM 10/25/2015"?

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct - I missed the fact there's another space involved.  There are several ways to solve this, for example by nesting `substring-after(substring-after(., ' '), ' ')`.